# response.body in Rspec controller test returns an empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec, devise

I'm trying to build a restful JSON api in Rails using the Devise gem and I have the following code:

**users_controller_spec.rb:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do

    describe "PUT/PATCH #update" do
    render_views
    context "when is successfully updated" do

      before(:each) do
        @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
        request.headers['Authorization'] = @user.auth_token
      end

      it "renders the json representation for the updated user" do
        user_response = json_response
        expect(user_response[:email]).to eq "newmail@example.com"
      end
  end
end
```

The issue I have is that `response.body` equals an empty string, which isn't valid JSON and hence I can't do `JSON.parse(response.body)`

I read elsewhere on SO to include `render_views` and you can see I've done that, but it makes no difference.

Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Is the response successful ? Print the `response.status`. You can also add `expect(response).to be_success` before parsing the body

Comment: You probably forgot to use `render json:` method

Comment: I have `render json:` in the `create` method of my application controller...

Comment: ok, I do not see `JSON.parse(response.body)` anywhere in the code that you have included... that means you haven't included all the relevant code. Can you please edit your question and include all the relevant code? we can't debug just one half (the spec) without the actual code of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the result was raising a permission error with a blank body because I didn't have a logged in user.  Check that your response is a success first.